# Unable to find loaction using Blackberry 8520 4.6.2 version phone

Tags: gps, blackberry, location

Here is the code i am using to get the location

```
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setHorizontalAccuracy(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
    criteria.setVerticalAccuracy(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
    criteria.setPreferredPowerConsumption(Criteria.POWER_USAGE_LOW);
    try {
        LocationProvider lp=LocationProvider.getInstance(criteria);
        if(lp !=null)
        {
              Location loc=null;
              loc=lp.getLocation(-1);
              if(loc!=null)
                   add(new EditField(loc.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLatitude()+"\n"+loc.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLongitude(),""));
              else 
                   add(new EditField("no location found",""));
        }
        else
        {
                add(new EditField("unable to find the location provider", ""));
        }
    } catch (LocationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This code was working well when used in a Blackberry Curve 8520 5.0 version, but when I installed this code on a Blackberry Curve 8520, it is showing a blank screen.

I also tried to debug it through USB debugging.  This is the result:

```
     [0.0] Starting version4_0
     [0.0] Started version4_0(216)   
     [0.0] Foreground version4_0(216) 
     [0.0] VM:+GC(f)w=11
     [0.0] VM:-GCt=63,b=1,r=0,g=f,w=11
     [0.0] VM:+CR
     [0.0] VM:-CR=39
     [0.0] VM:+GC(f)w=30
     [0.0] VM:-GCt=40,b=0,r=0,g=f,w=30
     [0.0] VM:+CR
     [0.0] VM:-CR=0
     [0.0] VM:+GC(f)w=30
     [0.0] VM:-GCt=36,b=0,r=0,g=f,w=30
     [0.0] VM:+CR
     [0.0] VM:-CR=0
     [0.0] VM:+GC(f)w=30
     [0.0] VM:-GCt=35,b=0,r=0,g=f,w=30
     [0.0] VM:+CR
     [0.0] VM:-CR=0
```

Can anyone please tell why my 4.6 version of black berry is not working?

Comment: Can the guy please post a comment who down voted my question?

Answer (score 0):

Which carrier? It matters when you try to get Cellsite based location.

Are you getting an exception? Are you getting a location with invalid coordinates? You can put all that information in popups so you can see it on device.